# plt.imshow not showing "sub" pictures

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualise incorrectly classified images using CNN on a dataset containing malaria infected and uninfected cells.

This is my code:

```
index=0
index_errors= []

for label, predict in zip(y_test,y_pred):
    if label != predict:
        index_errors.append(index)
    index +=1

plt.figure(figsize=(20,8))

for i,img_index in zip(range(1,17),random.sample(index_errors,k=16)):
    plt.subplot(2,8,i)
    plt.imshow(X_test[img_index])
    plt.title('Actual: '+str(y_test[img_index])+' Predict: '+str(y_pred[img_index]))
plt.show()
```

[image: The output]

For some reason the individual images are not showing, but I can't figure out what's causing this because I haven't gotten any errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are they "normalised" to values between 0 and 1? And do they show if you multiply everything by 255?

Comment: This solved the problem indeed. Thank you!